# Custom Task not visible in SSIS Toolbox

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I followed a tutorial in a Packt-Publishing Book to create a custom task. The book is about SQL Server 2012 Integration Services. Now I have SQL Server 2016 - maybe this makes a difference.

I was able to write a simple class for a task, that should delay execution for a given period of time.

My class inherits from `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Task` and overides the methods `Execute`, `InitializeTask` and `Validate`

I added the following class-decoration:

```
[DtsTask
        (
        DisplayName ="Delay Task",
        Description ="Just a test",
        IconResource ="Hourglass.ico",
        RequiredProductLevel =DTSProductLevel.None,
        TaskContact ="DelayTask"
        )]
```

In Project properties I signed the assembly and added the following Post-Build script:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\gacutil.exe" /u "$(TargetName)"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\gacutil.exe" /if "$(TargetPath)"
copy "$(TargetPath)" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Tasks" /Y
```

I can Build the Assembly without any issues and can see it in the target folder. Additionally I also copied the assembly in the x86 Program folder.

**Unfortunately I cannot see the Task in the SSIS-Toolbox!**

How can I deal with that??

Comment: Are you using SSDT with Visual Studio 2015 or later?   Try targeting the solution to SQL Server 2016.   That should tell it to look in the 130 folder.

Comment: Yes I use VS2019. Changing the targeting solution to SQL Server 2016 does not make the Custom Task appear :-(

Comment: Is it possible it didn't make it into the GAC?  Try changing TargetPath to [TargetFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-custom-objects/building-deploying-and-debugging-custom-objects?view=sql-server-ver15) or installing and confirming manually.

Comment: When I run `gacutil -l [AssemblyName]` I can see that it was successfully addded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason after hours of investigation.
I simple did not make the class public - blame on me !!!
Must be

```
public class DelayTask : Task {...}
```

and not

```
class DelayTask : Task {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still can't see it in toolbox, my class is set to public

```
[DtsTask(
    DisplayName = "Sales Force Import Task",
    Description = "Pulls data from Sales Force",
    UITypeName = "SForceLibrary.UI.SampleComponentUI, SForceLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f3a0d54ac94632fc",
    TaskType = "ImportTask",
    TaskContact = "ImportTask; InvenTrust Properties; Custom Sales Force Task",
    RequiredProductLevel = DTSProductLevel.None
    )]
public class ImportTask : Task
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32990989)